# IOS is it possible to get data of field of NSFetchedResultsController without casting

Tags: ios, casting, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have the following code:

```
if ([[frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] isKindOfClass:[Author class]])
    return ((Author *)[frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]).name;

return ((Location *)[frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]).name;
```

*frc* - `NSFetchedResultsController`.

How can I get data of identical field of objects `Author` and `Location`? Class must not know about the existence of Author and Location.

I also tried to do so:

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = m_arts.sections[indexPath.section];
id object = sectionInfo.objects[indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@", object[@"name"]); // Crash!!!
```

Comment: It belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to make `Location` and `Author` subclasses of `NamedObject` like this:

```
@interface NamedObject : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString *name;
@end

@interface Author : NamedObject
// ...
@end

@interface Location : NamedObject
// ...
@end
```

and then something like:

```
NamedObject *object = (NamedObject *) sectionInfo.objects[indexPath.row];
NSLog (@"%@", object.name);
```

to access the `name` property.

Comment: Thus we can remove unnecessary condition but the current class doesn't have to know about the base class too.